# The following tag(s) are not allowed: img [] [] after Magento upgrade

Tags: magento2, system.log

I recently upgraded from **2.2** to **2.3** but since then I get this on system.log

```
main.CRITICAL: The following tag(s) are not allowed: img [] []
```

Thanks :D

Comment: facing the same issue, hope somebody will fix it

Comment: Just for reference and narrow possibilities, it breaks paypal payments too? or it's not relatable?

Comment: my site is using SagePay, I think this issue doesn't specific to any payment

Comment: Ok that helps, you could understand when the error shows? if it's when opening a specific page or saving something? I have traffic in mine so it's hard to trace those things

Comment: I was thinking it's the same with this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25738. But the error tracker doesn't show any trace so I didn't know where the error comes from. The only thing that meaning is it's from /checkout/onepage/success/ page. My environment: Magento 2.3.5-p1 & PHP7.2.31

Comment: Well I get the date tag thing but, why should a img tag wouldn't be allowed? mine is Magento 2.3.5-p1 & PHP7.2.28

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for this but I may have some hints on how to debug this.
The error is logged in the method `Magento\Framework\Escaper::filterProhibitedTags()`: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5-p1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Escaper.php#L456
This private method is called by the `escapeHtml` method from the same class.
So this means that there is a call somewhere to `$block->escapeHtml($something)` where the parameter (`$something` in my example) contains an `<img>` tag and it is not allowed.

you can try to log the stacktrace of the error also.
A quick and dirty way of doing it, if you can reproduce this on a dev or staging environment (I don't recommend it for a live environment) is to replace the line mentioned above

```
$this->getLogger()->critical(
    'The following tag(s) are not allowed: ' . implode(', ', $notAllowedTags)
);
```

with

```
try {
    throw new \Exception()
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->getLogger()->critical(
        'The following tag(s) are not allowed: ' . implode(', ', $notAllowedTags) . ' Trace: '. $e->getTraceAsString();
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I can't test that on a dev environment because I don't know where the error is caused, I went to pages and tried to trigger the error but with no luck, it only triggers in the live website by some action I don't know to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I have identified that it is caused by a registered customer viewing their order

A similar issue to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25738 as @Jared Chu says but the solution for that issue doesn't work for this one

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was only fixed on the 2.4.x branch and will be available in the 2.4.2 release

For those on 2.3 branch I rolled a patch against 2.3.6 if anyone wants to give that a try

add this to your composer.json

```
        "magento/module-sales": {
            "[Remove in 2.4.2] Fixed issue with critical error: The following tag(s) are not allowed": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jordanvector/524a39a6bb201bb2a82639c490f5bacd/raw/af439647fc97b6c14f210755f66b41b49650e8de/2.3.6-Fixed-issue-with-critical-error-The-following-tags.patch"
        }
```